# Two Monarchy System Problem Solution

Tags: government

I want to create a two alternative monarchy system. I would like someone to help me improve upon that idea. The two monarchy system I would like to create is called democratic monarchy and non-bloodline monarchy.

The democratic monarchy is that a king can't have the crown price become king. It's that king's nephews and his children are elected by the citizen of the kingdom. So, the princes fight for approval from citizens. They can get approval from the citizens by helping the kingdom from various ways.

The non bloodline monarchy is that the king can't have his own kids to take the mantle. Instead the king adopts various talented children around the world  and train them to see who would become the king and take the monarchies name to their own.

The problem I'm facing is that corruption in the democratic system. Where the king wouldn't let his nephews become the king or not letting the general population vote for their best interest. The princes and other killing each other etc.

The other problem of non-bloodline system I'm facing is that what would be the appropriate age to adopt the children around the world? And what would be the best way to see who's talented and a way for it not become bloodline based monarchy?

Comment: The history of the Roman Republic and Empire (which should be mandatory reading for members here :-) ) show all of these features at work over the course of time.  People would legally adopt people to make it practical for them inherit authority from them (even ignoring their own natural children).  Likewise shared leadership roles and even formal splitting of the empire was common (arguably the norm).  However no one (including the Romans, who had the longest time to think about it) has ever found a way to avoid corruption of *any* system at *any* time.

Comment: Another good place to look is the Polish Lithuanian Commonwealth. They elected their king, sometimes for good, sometimes for bad. The king didn't have as much power in that system as in other monarchies though.

Comment: Have you heard of the [Nerva-Antonine adoptive dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerva–Antonine_dynasty)? What age were Trajan and Hadrian when they were adopted by emperors Nerva and Trajan respectively?

Comment: @AlexP Which worked until an emperor -- Marcus Aurelius -- had a son. Then the adoptive scheme went out the window and the era of the Five Good Emperors ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Arranged Marriage:

If you think the Charles & Di story was tragic, look at the marriages royals through history have endured. Royal marriages are almost never about love & attraction, or even compatibility. They are about power and talent.

To make a system where talent & ability can be joined to a royal system, allow the wives and husbands of royals to rule. Inheritance of titles is still through blood, but a parliament is responsible for selecting who the members of the royal family can marry. This can be by vote, or amongst a pool of candidates selected by a medical and intellectual evaluation (to weed out those with known family or mental/psychological problems). The potential future ruler can then be selected, married off to a son/daughter/cousin of the king/queen, and the current ruler may or may not have input into the process. Anyone found unworthy has their marriage annulled or is divorced. Free will really doesn't come into the equation.

You might want to use the term 'king' or 'queen' for the royal family member, and 'ruling consort' or something similar for whoever is making the actual decision-making.

A potential candidate may even be married before their candidacy, but their original marriages are either dissolved or polygamy is allowed and the marriage to the royal is considered the primary marriage.

This way, you maintain the royal bloodline, but at the same time the actual ruler is typically someone outside the royal family (unless an extraordinary royal is selected). If the king or queen (son/daughter of the previous ruler) is really talented, they could still be picked as the ruler over their consort.

This even allows the royal family to survive conquest and defeat in war - the conquerors simply marry into the family and become the new royal spouses. The true power is almost never handed to the children of the ruler, but passed to the most worthy candidate.

This somewhat sidesteps the corruption issue, since you still need a nominating system to pick who the ruler will be. If that system is corrupt, then the selection of the ruler will be corrupted. But there is no way even today to eliminate corruption from the ruler selection system.

Comment: What about restricting royal privileges and mixing with common citizen in school etc. Would that help to remove corruption?

Comment: @user84527 Keeping your royalty in touch with 'common' folk in medieval times would mean keeping them in touch with the wealthy elites and minor nobility. In my scenario, the actual role of the nobility is more symbolic, with royal marriage giving the royal stamp of legitimacy to the non-royal-family-born actual leader. If the royal has a partial role in influencing the ruler, then people might support such a move, and the citizens wouldn't be resentful of the true royals since they don't make the decisions. It would be like prime minister Kate had to marry Prince William to get the job.

Answer (score 0):

Nepotism or non-hereditary dictatorship?

I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you mean by a "two monarchy system"; are you trying to decide between two alternative systems (i.e. an elective monarchy where the incumbent ruler's children can't succeed, and a designative monarchy where the ruler adopts a bunch of children and picks the best one to be heir) or proposing a system that combines all these elements?

Assuming it's the former, I will say that historical precedent suggests both your systems will have corruption issues. Elective monarchies are actually very common historically (check out the Holy Roman Empire, Poland-Lithuania, Bohemia, Jerusalem, most Scandinavian kingdoms, etc) but the example which fits your system best is the Papal States; here the ruler is elected and his children cannot succeed him because, as a priest, he cannot have legitimate heirs. Many popes did therefore promote a number of their nephews and other relatives as potential successors, notably the Borgias; for instance, the uncle of Alexander VI (better known as Rodrigo Borgia) was Pope Callixtus III. Unfortunately, the Borgias' lurid reputation for scandal and the fact that such practices literally gave us the word 'nepotism' (original Latin meaning: nephew-ism) may give you a clue that this system did not exactly eliminate corruption. If anything, the need to find important jobs for a whole family network of potential heirs encourages rampant cronyism and patronage-politics even more than straightforward father-son succession does.

As for an adoptive monarchy, as others have noted the Roman Empire did practice this for a while quite successfully, but it broke down when emperors gave in to the temptation to pick their own sons instead. Arguably, many modern dictatorships also function this way, in that a ruler-for-life raises up a number of protegées and eventually designates one as the next supreme leader. I would suggest that there's not much point adopting potential heirs before adulthood, when you can pick those who are already proven politicians. Fitness for the complex, highly context-dependent task of national leadership is not like being good at maths or music; it's not a skill you can reliably identify among a whole country's worth of precocious children.

Finally, I'd conjecture that both your ideas seem to rely on the hope that a degree of healthy competition among potential heirs will produce the best outcome, but I don't think that's how these things usually go. In a monarchical society that is at least partly aristocratic, this competition will inevitably be waged largely through backdoor campaigns for favour and influence i.e. the very means most susceptible to corruption. The main advantage of non-hereditary monarchies is actually that they can avoid the problem of being stuck with an heir who is obviously unsuitable, such as a madman, a child, or (in a very patriarchal society) a woman. On the other hand, the main downside is that having a bunch of potential heirs in the running until the last minute is that - unless you have a very stable, strong state - the losing candidates become natural foci for dissent as anti-popes, pretenders to the throne, Ottoman-style fratricides, etc. So to cut a long story short, your systems have benefits if handled correctly, but also come with problems and are unlikely to significantly lessen corruption.

Answer (score 0):

### You're looking at a mixture of the Roman Empire and Scotland.

Let's take a look at the individual elements of your suggested system.

> The king can't have his own kids to take the mantle.

Interestingly enough, the Scottish actually used to do something like this. Under the Tanistry system the king's successor was one of the royal houses' chiefs, elected by the other house chiefs, in something akin to the Catholic College of Cardinals. This was used almost continuously in Scotland for 700 years, ending when Malcolm III killed Macbeth<sup>[1]</sup>.

> The princes fight for approval from citizens.

This is basically what the Romans did for their system of succession, which is why people like Vespasian were able to become Emperor without too much fuss<sup>[2]</sup>.

While both these systems worked very well, it's worth noting that they both had the same problem: helping your country is a lot of work, so hopeful successors spent much of their time arranging "accidents" for possible rivals.<sup>[3]</sup>

---

[1]: Yes, there was a real King Macbeth. It's worth noting that he wasn't the horrible guy Shakespeare portrayed him as; the houses had elected him Tanist (successor), so he was justified in his wrath against Duncan. He was, by all accounts, a very good king.

[2]: At least in theory.

[3]: The part of *Macbeth* immediately after King Duncan's murder does a pretty good job of showing what I'm talking about.